# How to determine the run time of a loop?

Tags: pdftex, loops, profiling

pdfTeX, provides two macros that can be used to determine the time elapsed from a run start. The first one determines the elapsed time in "scaled seconds", that means seconds divided by 65536.

```
\pdfelapsedtime
```

and the second one `\pdfresettimer` that resets the internal timer back to 0.

I got curious and ran the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fp,siunitx,ifthen}

\def\startTimer{\pdfresettimer}
\def\stopTimer{%
 \the\pdfelapsedtime\,scaled seconds
 \FPdiv\result{\the\pdfelapsedtime}{65536}
 \FPmul\result{\result}{1000000} %microseconds
 \FPround\result{\result}{6}\par 
 \result \si{\milli\second}\par}

\begin{document}
\startTimer
\newcount\n
\n=0
\loop%
   \advance\n by1
     \number\n, %  
   \ifnum\n<888%
\repeat% 3-4 scaled points
%% ifthen code 
\newcounter{acount}
\whiledo{\value{acount}<888}{%
\stepcounter{acount}% 
 \theacount, } %5-6 scaled points average
\stopTimer
\end{document}
```

My question is: Is this a good way to measure the efficiency of the loops? Are there any other ways? Can you please post your run times and your machine for comparison?

My results: "loop" [image] and "whiledo"  [image]

Comment: Your code only has one timer.

Comment: I suspect that what slows down the old-fashioned `\loop`...`\repeat` is that you are using `\texttt`, rather than `\theacount`. The former needs quite a few expansions, whereas the latter is just one "very simple" expansion.

Comment: @Bruno, I also wrote this in a now deleted answer, but Yiannis seems to have removed that code part in the mean time.

Comment: run time: first loop about 45 scaled seconds (without \texttt); second loop is about 1760 scaled seconds.

Comment: @Bruno @Caramdir sorry I edited while you were posting the delay was the `texttt` which I realized and edited the answer probably due to the loading of fonts? I run the code twice with the macros commented accordingly.

Comment: @Caramdir I only used one timer as it appears that once you start running the program you cannot reset the timer and start again. But maybe I am wrong.

Comment: @Yiannis: I think that just inserting `\stopTimer` and `\startTimer` between the two loops works. --- I get a similar result as Caramdir (factor of ~40 between the two).

Comment: @Bruno: yes it works but I get results that are very close for both (see edit).

Comment: @Yiannis: On what machine are you running this? On a normal desktop computer it seems unlikely that the code runs that much faster unless there is something that seriously slows down my computer.

Comment: @Caramdir Windows Vista - 32bit 4.00 GB RAM 2.4 GHz

Answer (score 5):

A general rule in timing statistics: do not trust any value below 1 full second.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, I'd say that's a reasonable way to measure the efficiency of loops. The body of each loop takes constant time as does the comparison. So the total time is just the combined time for the comparison and the body times the number of loop iterations.

In this case, the `\loop\repeat` loop is going to be a little faster because it has slightly less work to do for the comparison and body. If the two loops were substantially different implementations for the same problem, then testing a single number of iterations may not yield the fastest way to do it. Testing several different numbers of iterations would be more instructive.