# Is there a way to find out how long it took for my document to compile?

Tags: compiling

I was thinking it'd be nice to know how much time each package I load adds on to the total time between clicking "compile" and seeing the PDF come up on my screen, so that I can figure out which ones I shouldn't load unless necessary. If there were a way of measuring the precise amount of time it takes to compile (i.e., have the computer measure it, not try to approximate it by hand with a stopwatch), I can just remove one package at a time and measure the differences. But I can't find a way of doing this; I hunted around in the "log" file and didn't see this info, and I couldn't find any packages that add this functionality.

Ultimately, I admit it's not that big of a deal - compiling usually only takes a second, maybe two - but now I'm curious how to do this, and it could be relevant in much larger documents (with longer compile times).

Comment: Related question: [how to determine the run time of a loop](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9087/how-to-determine-the-run-time-of-a-loop)

Answer (score 18):

This is somewhat OS dependent.  On Linux and OS X you can use the `time` command from the command line.

```
time pdflatex myfile.tex
```

returns: (e.g.)

```
real    0m1.976s
user    0m0.331s
sys     0m0.091s
```

There may be a similar command in Windows.  Depending on your editing environment, you can probably modify the latex command from within the editor (temporarily) to run the time command when you compile, which would make checking the times for different package configurations easier.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! As I should have mentioned in my question, I'm using TeXnicCenter on Windows, and I'm afraid I don't have any experience running LaTeX (or anything else) from a command line. But I suppose this is good motivation to figure that out :) When you say "modify the latex command", how would I do that in something like TeXnicCenter?

Comment: @Zev since Windows doesn't have an exact parallel to the unix `time` command, it's not so obvious how to do this in Windows. There are a bunch of suggestions here: [How to measure execution time of command in Windows command line](http://stackoverflow.com/q/673523). I don't know how easy any of these would be to integrate with TeXnicCenter.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the link - I suppose it might be more involved to do then.

Answer (score 12):

If you are using the `pdftex` engine, you can measure the time that each package takes to be loaded by adding the following near the start of your document.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\typeoutthetime}
  {\typeout{\strip@pt\dimexpr\pdfelapsedtime sp\relax sec.}}
\edef\@popfilename
  {%
    \unexpanded\expandafter{\@popfilename}%
    \noexpand\typeoutthetime
  }
\makeatother
```

You could also hook similarly at the end of the document with Heiko Oberdiek's `atveryend` package: `\AtVeryVeryEnd{\typeoutthetime}`.

Comment: Where does it print the result? I saw from the the log file the package was executing the hook, but it didn't seem to output anything in the log. :/

Comment: @JoonasD6 In the log file.

Comment: In my project, I'm getting this and no compilation time after that:
`Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AfterLastShipout' on input line 542. 
    (/compile/output.aux)`
    `Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AtVeryEndDocument' on input line 542.`
    `Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AtEndAfterFileList' on input line 542.`

But I just noticed in a new file that I do get:

    `Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtVeryVeryEnd' on input line 28.
    0.31827sec.`

Hmm. (I apologise for code formatting; spaces didn't seem to block it correctly.)

Comment: In what you copied there is a time: "0.31827sec".

Comment: Yes, but that only appeared in a new, clean test file. The first log entries (concerning the project I actually do need to time) which say "empty hook", didn't have any seconds after them. Wonder if some package conflict or something can result in the hook failing.

Comment: It's hard to debug what you're describing without having the code.  Please post a separate question linking to this answer, you'll get quicker help, sorry.

Answer (score 11):

By default ConTeXt gives

```
system          | total runtime: 35.093
```

at the end of each compile. This is the cumulative for all the runs needed to resolve references, etc. For more detailed usage, there is a `timing` module, which gives a graphical output of the resources used per page.

```
\usemodule[timing]
\starttext
 ,,,
 ...
\page
\ShowUsage{}
\stoptext
```

The output is similar to the graphs shown in Chapter XIX of the [Mk manual](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/mk.pdf).

Comment: Is there anything that ConTeXt *can't* do? :-)

Comment: It can't reach the mass for now (I'd like to know why).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm not sure that ConTeXt is right for me; I'm mainly using LaTeX to type my math homework, and I don't think I need anything fancy (or at least, the discussion [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4987/why-should-i-be-interested-in-context) mainly went over my head or wasn't important to me). But it's good to know that this ability exists elsewhere.

Answer (score 10):

The [regstats](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/regstats) package with option "timer" gives the time needed for
the specific (pdflatex) compilation run, using `\pdfelapsedtime`.

```
%% When compiling with lua(la)tex (and wanting to use option timer=true)
%% the following line must be uncommented (i.e. remove the "%% ").
%% \directlua{starttime = os.clock()}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[timer=true]{regstats}[2012/04/01]
\begin{document}
When option \verb|timer| (or \verb|timer=true|) is chosen, also the time
needed for the compilation run is given. The used \verb|\pdfelapsedtime|
is not available, when lua(la)tex is used instead of pdf(la)tex to compile
the document. In that case at the very beginning of your TeX file say
\verb|\directlua{starttime = os.clock()}|
(even before \verb|\documentclass|!), and the timer option can also be
used with lua(la)tex. When neither lua(la)tex nor pdf(la)tex is used
to compile the document, the timer(-option) does not work.

For the resulting message, please compile and have a look at the end
of the log-file.

Because the compilation time for this example is usually quite short,
option \texttt{timer} is not demonstrated very spectacular.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

`TeX`, `LaTeX` and all its distributives offer (at least since version 3)
a compilation command `-time-statistics`.

(You can find a list of compilation options and commands,
by opening a command line and execute `latex --help`.)

Not sure though, wether (and how) one may invoke this compilation command directly from `.tex` files.
Compare for example `\batchmode` to invoke `-interaction=batchmode`.

Still hope this may be useful to someone. :)

Besides, here's what its execution looks like:
[image]

Comment: This is probably only for MiKTeX. There's no such option in TeX Live binaries.

Comment: Ahhh that is too bad. (Just found it and seemed useful.) Do you think I should adjust the answer then?

Comment: +1 I just checked, on MikTeX the order is available, elsewhere, I don't know.

Comment: @AndréC: Thanks for checking! Yes,it seems weird since it isn't clear wether this is a MikTex specific command, or Tex command..

Answer (score 1):

You need to download timeit from [Windows 2003 Resource Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd&DisplayLang=en). 
Then run in Windows command line:

```
timeit xelatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode C:\Users\USERNAME\test_directory\test.tex.
```

It worked on Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

[latexmk](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexmk) has the option `-time`.
It will output the time of each pass of the TeX-engine as well as the accumulated total time to generate all the documents.
For example, the command

```
latexmk -pdf -silent -time file.tex
```

gives the output

```
Latexmk: Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
Latexmk: Run number 2 of rule 'pdflatex'
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
'pdflatex  -interaction=batchmode -recorder  "file.tex"': time = 0.23
'pdflatex  -interaction=batchmode -recorder  "file.tex"': time = 0.26
Accumulated processing time = 0.57
```