# Drawing this figure using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I am interested in creating the following figure using TikZ, although I am really new to this "machinery".

[image]

Thanks to [this old post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/547594/more-natural-looking-circle-around-math-using-tikz), I managed to create the following

[image]

QUESTIONS:

1. How can I add all these little balls inside and around the shape?
2. How can I add the corresponding letter notation?
3. Is there a way that the color of the boundary can be changed?

Many many thanks in advance for the time and the help!

Comment: Your questions refer to very basic functions of tikz: 1.  
`\node[circle, fill=red] (c) at (0,0){};`, 2. `\node (o) at (x, y) {$\Omega$};`, 3. set `draw=<color>` in the options. I recommend learning some basics about tikz. Furthermore, only one question per page should be asked here.

Comment: Reading the "Minimal Intro" at https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf already will help you, so the big manual will be less frightening, but a consulting source. Also checking the Tikz gallery might be inspiring: https://texample.net/tikz/examples/ .

Comment: @dexteritas thank you very much, but I was in a kind of rush, this is why I thought to ask first here. In any case, next time I'll try to show more effort by my side. But Tikz have been always scary to me :/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While you are waiting for some tikz-help, here is a version in [Metapost](https://tug.org/metapost.html) making use of the two random number generators: `uniformdeviate n` and `normaldeviate`.

[image]

You should compile this with `lualatex` (or work out how to adapt it for plain MP):

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
% make some nice colours
color orange, berry, claret, pine;
orange = 1/256(252, 128, 8);
berry = 1/256(70, 122, 168);
claret = 1/256(168, 75, 68);
pine = 1/256(74, 170, 122);

% define a roughly circular boundary
path boundary;
boundary = for i=0 upto 7: (50 + uniformdeviate 20) * dir (45i-30) .. endfor cycle;

% and draw it with a thick pen and in orange
draw boundary withpen pencircle scaled 3 withcolor orange;

% put 12 random green circles inside the boundary
for i=1 upto 12:
    path p; p = fullcircle scaled 4 
        shifted (uniformdeviate 7/8)[origin, point uniformdeviate 8 of boundary];
    fill p withcolor pine; draw p;
endfor

% and now add n red/blue circles round the outside
numeric t, n, dt;
t = 0; n = 32; 2 dt = arclength boundary / n;
for i=1 upto n-1:
    t := t + 5/4 dt + 3/2 uniformdeviate dt;
    numeric a; a = arctime t of boundary;
    path p; p = fullcircle scaled 4
        shifted point a of boundary
        shifted 4 unitvector(direction a of boundary rotated -90);
    fill p withcolor if normaldeviate > 0: claret else: berry fi;
    draw p; 
endfor

% add labels, the "-30" in the definition of boundary
% means that the 0 point is roughly bottom right
label.ulft("$\Omega$", point 0 of boundary);
label.lrt("$\Gamma$", point 0 of boundary) withcolor orange;
    
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

It will (of course) give you slightly different output each time you compile it, and as I did not put in any aesthetic checking for collisions you may need to compile it several times before you get a nice looking diagram.

You can find tutorials and reference material for Metapost by following the link at the top.

### Notes

- `uniformdeviate n` returns a random number, uniformly distributed between 0 and `n`, where `n` is any valid MP number.  The *mean* value returned will be roughly `1/2 n` if you call it enough times.
- `normaldeviate` returns a random number that is normally distributed with mean = 0 and standard deviation = 1.   Roughly half the numbers returned will be negative, and very few of them will be outside the range (-3, 3).
- The colours are defined as RGB colours.  MP uses a tuple of three numbers to represent an RGB colour, and expects each of the three elements to be between 0 and 1.  Any values less than 0 are clipped to 0 and any value > 1 are clipped to 1.  So to represent the WebSafe colour `#FF6633`, you need first to make it into a decimal tuple `(255, 102, 51)`, then reduce all the values to the range 0 to 1 instead of 0 to 255.  You can do this simply by dividing the tuple by 255 like so `(255, 102, 51)/255` or because MP supports fraction constants and implicit multiplication `1/255(255, 102, 51)`.
- If you prefer to use regular colours defined in your Latex doc, then using another bit of `luamplib` magic, you can still access them in a MP graphic.  So if you have (say) `\definecolor{mmm}{rgb}{.6, .3, .1}` in your regular LaTeX preamble, then you could use this directly inside an `mplibcode` environment like this:

  ```
    draw boundary withcolor \mpcolor{mmm};
  ```

Comment: Many thanks for the time and the effort! Just one quick question: How can I change the colors here? I see you define them in a way other than the usual (to me), that is \definecolor, rgb, etc...Where can I find these combinations so for instance to change the orange color? Once again thank u:)

Comment: Look up the Metapost reference manual §6.1 for details of how to define a `color` variable. But I will update the notes here as well.